# How can I spot class redefinitions?

Tags: python

Here is a very simple setup:

```
class A(object):
    x = 1

class B(object):
    x = 2

class C(object):
    x = 3

class B(B):
    x = 4

class C(object):
    x = 5

print A.x, B.x, C.x
```

which outputs the expected:

```
1, 4, 5
```

is it possible to detect that B has been 'redefined' but C has been 'replaced'? either during the creation phase or subsequently by inspecting the objects?

These classes are being used as configuration objects, there is a loader class above this which imports the module and then introspects to find the classses and their attributes which are then used by the application to instance named parameters. e.g.

```
class tcp_port(number):
    minimum = 1024
    maximum = 2048
```

really python is just being used as a convenient scripting language to define parameters in the main app. These files are available for edit by that most dangerous of people: The Customer So the requirement is to be able to detect at run time if a class has (accidentally) reused a name that has already been defined, but to safely pass the occasional case where a class is redefined, but then tweaks or add some attribute:

```
class tcp_port(tcp_port):
    maximum = 4096
```

So... I'm hoping for some runtime sanity checker rather than a lint-like solution. Also, this needs to happen when the class is defined, not instanced.

... is there global function which gets called to create a class (or any other object)? a bit like have a `__new__` but in the global context?

Comment: Do you need to detect it programmatically or just be notified while reading the code?

Comment: I've updated the question with more detail -- detect programmatically.

Comment: Hmm.  It's not really a good use case for inheritance, like this.  Are you aware that `class B(B)` actually keeps the old `B` hanging around, it's not a proper monkeypatch?  Check in `B.mro()` to see a reference to the previously defined `B`.  My suggestion would be to store the data provided by "The Customer" in some simpler data structure and parse from that.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately many years of history would make that tricky that stage, but your point is noted; thanks! the `mro()` call obviously gives a good method to detect a redefinition though. so, can I somehow spot the discard of `C` ?

Comment: Yes, I will post another answer about that, but I'll leave the linting answer since it could be a more helpful approach for other readers.

Comment: You seem to be able to expect from the user that she/he inherits from `object`. You could redefine `object` to be  a wrapper class of `object`  so that its `__new__` method peeks into the global namespace before class creation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by defining a parent class for all the classes then using a metaclass to keep a track of the names of the classes created, check for 'derived from itself' and then report any names that were reused.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class _Object_Meta(type):
    _defined = set()
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        for base in bases:
            if name == base.__name__:
                break
            else:
                if name in _Object_Meta._defined:
                    raise RuntimeError("%s redefined" % name)
        _Object_Meta._defined.add(name)

class Object(object):
    __metaclass__ = _Object_Meta

class A(Object):
    x = 1

class B(Object):
    x = 2

class C(Object):
    x = 3

class B(B):
    x = 4

class C(Object):
    x = 5
```

Answer (score 3):

If the class was redefined in-place, it will have old versions of itself hanging around in the MRO:

```
>>> [x for x in A.mro() if x.__name__ == A.__name__]
[__main__.A]
>>> [x for x in B.mro() if x.__name__ == B.__name__]
[__main__.B, __main__.B]
>>> [x for x in C.mro() if x.__name__ == C.__name__]
[__main__.C]
```

So you could detect that occurrence:

```
def has_redefinition_inplace(classobj):
    types = [x for x in classobj.mro() if x.__name__ == classobj.__name__]
    return len(types) > 1
```

This would not be 100% reliable, because there could be legitimately be colliding class names coming into the MRO from different modules.

Comment: You could make it 100% reliable by enforcing CamelCase and not importing `*` ;)

Comment: Does a definition via `class Foo: pass` followed by a redefinition via `class Foo: pass`, all in the same file and not `import`ed, constitute an in-place redefinition?

Answer (score 1):

A good linter will warn on re-declarations without usage. And a good IDE will lint directly in the editor.

For example, PyCharm will highlight these class names with a warning colour:

[image: redeclared screencap]

Another good way to spot these is with [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1x/) in your test suite.  Functions with names that were overwritten (common copy-paste errors) can not have test coverage in the function body.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've updated the question with a little more of the background and the request for a non lint-like solution.